# Execute msg from a service

Tags: windows, service, cmd

A have a system service that can receive and execute cmd commands remotely.
Everything works except the msg command on Windows 10.
In Windows 7 it shows the desired message, but on Windows 10 it shows nothing.
I know service can't access the GUI, but i don't understand why works on Windows 7, but not on Windows 10.
This is the command: `msg /v username "message message"`

Comment: What is this system service? Did you write the code for the system service? App questions should generally go to https://superuser.com/

Comment: Written by myselft.

Comment: So... The problem was with the Win10 msg.exe.
After I replaced it with the Win7 version, the messages are showed on Win10 too

Answer (score 0):

The builtin msg.exe in Windows 10 and Windows 11 is a 64-bit app so you need to use this path to start it from a service:

C:\WINDOWS\Sysnative\msg.exe